# New Messages notification in iOS With 'Parse'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, livechat

Recently, i'm doing a project of building a ios-based chat app like 'whatsapp' or 'Line'.
I want to build a database for the messages transmitted between different users( commonly on different devices). 
I find the 'Parse' solution for the database and notification center.

[Doc of 'Parse' solution for pushing notifications and related database](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/iOS)

But what i have read from the docs is that

> The notification of 'Parse' is to broadcast a ad or a news for a wide
>   range of subscribes to the certain channels.

I hope that i get it wrong because i have no idea that a 1-on-1 chat app would be notified in this way. I have imagined that in the backend of this app of such circumstance , a user subscribes to a list of users(friends) which is unique from others. And when someone naming A is sending a message to another one naming B. B would get the notification of that new message and force the app to reload the data in the tableview. This turns out to be very time-consuming and not efficient.
Is there a efficient way to implement the notification and chat function within the scope of "Parse"

Comment: Why is that inefficient? And anything you code worth coding is time consuming. You don't get professional results from a 3 minute session.

Comment: What I mean about inefficient is that the Parse would keep a list of friends for every use ,which would be storage inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean for every use? Parse only does what you tell it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a built in Chat inside my app using a github library called JSQMessages. I also use Parse as my backend. I don't do anything with the channels. What I did was create some logic. If there are messages query for the conversation object and if there aren't, leave the view blank. After creating the first message, we create and save the conversation and also the message. Each message has a "convoID" which is the conversation's objectId. So each message can be pulled in by convoID. The objectId of an object never changes.

As far as the notifications I handled my push notifications. I queried in my installation database class for users with their objectId's in the array of the receivers in the conversation and made sure it excluded the current user. Once that is done I reload the messages from the sent notification because it fires off a method if I am in that view controller that picks up the notification sent through the Notification Center. (I have in an app banner that'll act as a push notification banner inside my own app)

If you would like to see what I have done I get throw in some code here but although it may seem lengthy, it is the only way I see it working.

**Some added code**

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"userID" containedIn:messageReceiverObject[@"receivers"]];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"userID" notEqualTo:self.senderId];
NSDictionary *data = @{@"alert":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@: %@", self.senderDisplayName, messageReceiverObject[@"lastMessage"]], @"badge":@"increment", @"content-available":@"1", @"sound":@"", @"m": @"message"};
[PFPush sendPushDataToQueryInBackground:pushQuery withData:data];
```

what this does is it queries the installation class in the database and then it send that push data from the NSDictionary to those users. Notice how I un-included my self from the query because right after I just call `[self loadMessages];` which loads all my messages

Comment: You mean that a conversation between A and B has a convoID like 123456 and every messages between them share the same value for its own attribute convoID?
Another question is do u mean that once A sends a message to B(or a bunch of guys). Those guys's app.would fire off an action to reload the data? But how do u  send notifications to exactly these guys? i mean is how can the notification be sent to a dynamic group of people(or single). i dont know it thoroghly.

Comment: The first question...exactly. The second question....I am assuming you're familiar with PFInstallation which is the Push data class in the Parse database for your app. When the user logs into my app, I set the a pointer in the column (in the PFinstallation class for [PFInstallation currentInstallation]) that is associated with that currentUser to [PFUser current] (whoever that may be) and then I set another column called "userID" which is the [PFUser current].objectId. As for as sending a push to a dynamic group of people look my added code. @Bill

Comment: I have seen the added code. i find out that i miss the fact that the Parse can send the notifications to the device owner (same as the account owner) sooner or later. all i have to do is just push the notifications to the specified devices. Is that right? And if the receiver checks that notification and the messages the state of the conversation would change to normal ? thx a lot !

Comment: Yeah that is partially correct but you want to associate each device with the current user. Also when the user logs out you want to set those fields to nothing because they shouldn't receive pushes if they aren't signed in. So when sending messages through send to that device or devices with that user object or user object id. I'm glad I could help though. If you could make this as the answer that would be greatly appreciated! @Bill

Comment: Do you deploy some cloud code on parse? Is that a good option for chat app?@kylecman

Comment: @Bill i was thinking about that for the sole purpose of checking for duplicate conversations objects because if 2 user send a message to each other at the same exact time there would be two conversations which wouldn't be good. You can do something in cloud code that'll query for that convo object and if it returns true, it'll stop the object from being and false it'll create the necessary object. Cloud code is written javascript which is something I will have to learn at some point time. Using cocoapods and ruby is new to me as well.

Comment: @Bill but the best and easiest way is just create objects, save them, reload the view, send out pushes, and re-query for messages. There is no real easy, non time consuming way to do it.